# Animations for Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation

Is there a library except Android Arsenal in which animations are available'
Or is there a way to create an animation outside of android studio and import it?
A lot of apps have these animations does anybody know how they do that?

Comment: What is wrong with the Android built-in animations?

Comment: Where are they i am new to this

Comment: Use this library, You'll find plenty of animations in this library:-https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

Comment: I mean more complex animations something like:https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Lottie from AirBnb:  https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

It allows you to import After Effects animations.  I've used it to share the same animation produced by my designer in both Android and iOS apps.

Comment: Thanks a lot
that was EXACTLY was I was searching for